# how to return text with link in map function using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to do a autocomplete input box, getting data from a `<ul>`, I can get the auto complete working but I want the results to have links. So users can click on the result and go to the page.

```
$(function() {
  var availableTags = $('ul > li > a').map(function() {
return this.href;
 }).toArray();

$("#tags").autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});



 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<label>Items autocomplete</label>
<input id="tags" type="text" style="width: 200px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span id="results_count"></span>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="aaaa">1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="aabb">1.1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="aacc">1.2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="aabb">1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="bbcc">1.1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="aabc">1.2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`select`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) event, which fires when an item is selected, eg:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function() {
        location.href = this.value;
    }
});
```

In response to your comment, just change your `.map()` to return an array of objects, each containing a `value` (the link), and `label` (the text):

```
var availableTags = $('ul > li > a').map(function() {
    return { 'value': this.href, 'label': $(this).text() };
}).get();
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The results are links, but they aren't the same links as the one in the <li>. Is it possible to have the auto completes to be have the same link and text <li><a href="bbcc">1.1</a></li>